# Can i display a memory address (d.dump) typecasted to a specific structure type?

Tags: trace32

I am trying to view a structure passed as argument to my function.. However while debugging in Trace32 it is only showing me the start address of the structure, but not complete strucute. I can see the values in memory dump at that location, but i want to format the memory location with my structure type, to visualize the values of each data members. Can i do that ?

Comment: Please provide code examples.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the command you are looking for is `Var.View` (or `Var.Watch`).

E.g.

```
Var.View %Open (struct mystruct_s *)0x00007890
```

The `Dump.*` commands deal with raw memory. Any symbol used with those are considered just as an address.

The `Var.*` commands deal with high level language expressions, which basically means C/C++ syntax, which also considers C/C++ data types.